# "Citations" dans un texte suivi

Tags: littérature, ponctuation, majuscules, écriture

Tout d'abord désolé pour ce titre, je ne savais pas comment le formuler. Ma compagne a commencé à lire [L'Anomalie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Anomalie) et m'a fait remarquer ce matin que certaines phrase l'avaient laissée perplexe. Je n'ai pas d'extrait sous les yeux, mais voici un exemple de ma propre invention:

> ... et ces groupes de cyclistes à qui l'on a envie de crier Allez les gars, encore un effort, l'arrivée n'est plus très loin, mais qui sont déjà loin avant que l'on ait pu prononcer un seul mot.

Ce qui la perturbait est le fait que ce "Allez les gars, encore un effort, l'arrivée n'est plus très loin"

- Ne soit pas encadré de guillemets ni d'aucune forme de ponctuation particulière
- Commence par une majuscule, bien qu'il soit en milieu de phrase

Même si les quelques extraits qu'elle m'a montrés en exemple ne présentaient pas vraiment d'ambiguïté, je dois bien avouer que je me demande aussi si cette manière de faire est "correcte" et commune. Ayant la même difficulté à  chercher une réponse en ligne que pour décrire cela dans le titre de ma question, je me tourne donc vers vous.

- Comment cette formulation s'appelle-t-elle ? (le fait de rapporter une parole par écrit) Une citation ?
- Existe-t-il des "règles" quant à la manière de formuler cela par écrit ?

Comment: Le terme que tu cherches est [discours direct](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discours_direct).

Comment: Je suis un peu embêté, ce commentaire et le lien répondent pleinement à la question. Si le commentaire était un peu plus élaboré en réponse je l'accepterais bien volontiers. Mais néanmoins déjà merci pour cette réponse qui n'en est pas une :-) Je comprends aussi que manifestement cette manière d'écrire ne semble pas habituelle, dans la mesure ou on attend quand-même une autre forme de ponctuation. Mais soit, après tout loin de moi l'idée de critiquer un Goncourt :-)

Comment: La règle générale est que le discours direct est entre guillemets, donc la question de l'absence de guillemets reste. Certes, c'est plus une question de littérature que de langue.

Comment: +1 pour t'encourager à poser davantage de questions...

Comment: Merci :-) Je ne suis pas un grand poseur de questions sur SE, car souvent quand je m'en pose une, j'y trouve déjà la réponse peu importe le site :-)

Answer (score 1):

La littérature est un art tout comme la peinture ou la musique ou simplement le dessin.

Avant tout l'art se focalise sur l'expression ; alors s'il faut passe outre les règles (grammaire, méthodologie ...) pour s'exprimer, pourquoi un artiste (l'écrivain) n'oserait pas ?!

Tout ceci fait penser au réalisme dans l'histoire de la littérature ...

Pour m'adresser directement à la question, je dirai que l'auteur tenait surtout à ce que le lecteur se concentre sur la crudité des "faits" ou "actions" ... que son attention reste et suive le "flow"